# Excel - revert back to original data types

Tags: excel, type-conversion

I was given an excel file (.xlsx) and of course when I open it, Excel guesses the data types which are wrong. Is there any way of opening that file, with another tool perhaps, without it guessing the datatype.
Or, is there something I can do to revert back once it is opened?

The biggest issues is I have `House Number` columns which at times looks like `11-13` which Excel turns into a data. When I try to change the type to text, it gives be the default count of seconds since 1970.

Comment: The XLSX file will be re-opened with the same data types as when it was saved. I don't think there is any case where Excel re-infers the data type differently from when the file was created. Is the problem really that your data comes from some other data source, such as a csv file?

Comment: I think the problem was that the data was exported or maybe copied into excel and it changed some of the house numbers into dates.
I was hoping there would be a way to revert that, but maybe not after it was already saved.

Answer (score 0):

The first two comments seem to be correct. Once Excel has mis-interpretted the values as dates, the initial text has been lost. You enter "11-13" and Excel thinks it is a date (1 Nov 2013) and stores that as the number 41579 -- which is the number of days from 1 Jan 1900 to 1 Nov 2013.

If the same pattern is recurring many times and you don't want to fix them all manually, the following formula may be useful: `=MONTH(A1)&"-"&RIGHT(YEAR(A1),2)`. That takes the corrupted value in A1 and reconstructs the original string.